# LATEX Tikz shading region between polar plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texworks, polarplot

I'm attempting to use just Tikz to shade in the region within the polar plot but outside of the internal circle as seen in the screenshot below...

I understand that pgf plots might be the better package to use, although I am very unfamiliar with it, speaking of which I'm very new to Tikz as well. This is my first post here, as I am unable to find previous posts that answer this particular question. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

[[image]]

This is the code that I have completed so far, but as you can see, I'm struggling to un-shade the internal circle.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

% cartesian coordinates
\draw[-] (-1cm,0cm) -- (3cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0cm,-2cm) -- (0cm,2cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};

% axis labels and tick marks
\foreach \x in {-1,0,...,3}
    \draw(\x,3pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[fill=white, below] {\footnotesize$\x$};

\foreach \y in {-2,-1,...,2}
    \draw(-3pt,\y) -- (3pt,\y) node[fill=white, right] {\footnotesize$\y$};

% cosine graph
\draw [thick,color=black,domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar 
cs:angle=\x r,radius= {1+1*cos(\x r)});
\draw [thick,color=black,domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar 
cs:angle=\x r,radius= {cos(\x r)});

% shading
\fill [fill=gray!50!white, opacity=0.3] plot [domain=0:2*pi] (xy polar 
cs:angle=\x r,radius= {1+1*cos(\x r)});

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

The following picture is what this code produced...
[image]

Comment: `PGFPlots` is super easy to use, and gives consistent plots - I recommend to look into the `polaraxis` for this plot. I do not know how to make your plot, but here something similar is done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367094/shading-between-the-graphs-of-two-polar-equations-in-pgfplots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By building the circle with the `circle` operation and not with the plot operation, it is possible to use the `even odd rule`. (see page 172 of 3.0.1a TikZ's manual).

#### Update: By applying the fill opacity=.3 parameter

as indicated by @marmot in its commentary.

[image: even odd rule]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

% cartesian coordinates
\draw[-] (-1cm,0cm) -- (3cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0cm,-2cm) -- (0cm,2cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};

% axis labels and tick marks
\foreach \x in {-1,0,...,3}
    \draw(\x,3pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[fill=white, below] {\footnotesize$\x$};

\foreach \y in {-2,-1,...,2}
    \draw(-3pt,\y) -- (3pt,\y) node[fill=white, right] {\footnotesize$\y$};

% cosine graph
\filldraw [thick,even odd rule,fill=gray!50,fill opacity=.3,domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar 
cs:angle=\x r,radius= {1+1*cos(\x r)})(0.5,0)circle(5mm);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the plotted shape outline black instead of a darker gray? Also brilliant work, thank you!

Comment: @salami_pirate Yes, by using `fill opacity=0.3` instead of `opacity=0.3`.